# Device for sim to cable phone

Tags: sim

I know that this question might not right here.. But i do not know where to post it else.
Is there any device, which I can put a sim card in. And then connect a good old cable connected phone to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can! These are call GSM to PSTN adapter. Check out [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Wireless-GSM-Mobile-Cell-Cellular-to-Landline-Phone-Line-Converter-Clear-Voice-IMEI-Changeable-Quad-band/404544_370230024.html) & [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HJM6K7E).

Update : More seller at [here](http://www.telephone-systems.com.au/aristel/aristel-cellular-gateway-and-gsm-diallers.html), [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CYM2URI) & [here](http://www.voicecti.com/telephony-products/26/gsm-mobile-telephony-solution)

Comment: Badly the first one isnt available now.. The second one is too expensive..

Comment: Let me know where you belong from? I will find the cheapest one for you or else you can search for GSM to PSTN adapter on the internet.

Comment: That would be very kind of you. I am from Austria.

Comment: Have you found anything better?

Comment: No sorry, but tell me what you want more?

Comment: Oh sorry, i did not see that you updated your answer... Also very expensive...